# Custom category page with taxonomy filters

Tags: wp-query, filters, taxonomy

Wordpress custom category page that filters from URL.

I have two taxonomies - offer and network

On custom category page load nothing appears. Even when I use OR or AND.

When I filter I sometime get the correct display.

I believe the problem is in the else statement. Can anyone see the problem? WHat am I doing wrong?

```
if (isset($_GET['offer']) && !empty($_GET['offer']))
    {
        $offer = $_GET['offer'];
    }

    else
    {
                    **$offer = '';**
    }


if (isset($_GET['network']) && !empty($_GET['network']))
    {
        $network = $_GET['network'];
    }
    else
    {
                    $network = '';
    }


'tax_query' => array(

    'relation' => 'OR',

  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'offer',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $offer,
    'operator' => 'IN'
  ),

  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'network',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $network,
    'operator' => 'IN'
  ),

),
```

Comment: Could you post some bigger part of your code? It's hard to say what this code will look like, since you cut it in such way, that it's even not a correct code anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution: Add 'operator' => 'AND', to the tax_query.

```
'tax_query' => array(

'relation' => 'OR',

array(

    'taxonomy' => 'offer',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array($offer),
      'operator' => 'AND',
),

array(

    'taxonomy' => 'network',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array($network),
      'operator' => 'AND',
),
```